# cannot run application on server

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I wanted to try example of `oauth` servlet on salesforce.com.

But the problem is that I can't run application on the server because it always fails with same error

I've created `dynamic web project` and my project structure looks like this
[image]

Servlet I completely copied

```
@WebServlet(name = "oauth", urlPatterns = { "/oauth/*", "/oauth" }, initParams = {
    @WebInitParam(name = "clientId", value = "xxxx"),
    @WebInitParam(name = "clientSecret", value = "xxxx"),
    @WebInitParam(name = "redirectUri", value = "https://localhost:8443/DemoREST/oauth/_callback"),
    @WebInitParam(name = "environment", value = "https://login.salesforce.com"), })
public class OAuthServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
private static final String INSTANCE_URL = "INSTANCE_URL";

private String clientId = null;
private String clientSecret = null;
private String redirectUri = null;
private String environment = null;
private String authUrl = null;
private String tokenUrl = null;

public void init() throws ServletException {
    clientId = this.getInitParameter("clientId");
    clientSecret = this.getInitParameter("clientSecret");
    redirectUri = this.getInitParameter("redirectUri");
    environment = this.getInitParameter("environment");

    try {
        authUrl = environment
                + "/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id="
                + clientId + "&redirect_uri="
                + URLEncoder.encode(redirectUri, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }

    tokenUrl = environment + "/services/oauth2/token";
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String accessToken = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(
            ACCESS_TOKEN);

    if (accessToken == null) {
        String instanceUrl = null;

        if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("oauth")) {
            // we need to send the user to authorize
            response.sendRedirect(authUrl);
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Auth successful - got callback");

            String code = request.getParameter("code");

            HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

            PostMethod post = new PostMethod(tokenUrl);
            post.addParameter("code", code);
            post.addParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            post.addParameter("client_id", clientId);
            post.addParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
            post.addParameter("redirect_uri", redirectUri);

            try {
                httpclient.executeMethod(post);

                try {
                    JSONObject authResponse = new JSONObject(
                            new JSONTokener(new InputStreamReader(
                                    post.getResponseBodyAsStream())));
                    System.out.println("Auth response: "
                            + authResponse.toString(2));

                    accessToken = authResponse.getString("access_token");
                    instanceUrl = authResponse.getString("instance_url");

                    System.out.println("Got access token: " + accessToken);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new ServletException(e);
                }
            } finally {
                post.releaseConnection();
            }
        }

        // Set a session attribute so that other servlets can get the access
        // token
        request.getSession().setAttribute(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);

        // We also get the instance URL from the OAuth response, so set it
        // in the session too
        request.getSession().setAttribute(INSTANCE_URL, instanceUrl);
    }

    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/DemoREST");
}
}
```

But when I try it to run on server I've got and error.

```
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;D:\installed\Git1.8\cmd;D:\installed\cURL\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;D:\installed\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;D:\installed\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;D:\installed\luna\eclipse;D:\installed\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin;D:\installed\Git1.7.7.1\cmd;D:\installed\gradle-1.7\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin;D:\installed\cURL\bin;D:\installed\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin;;.
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Salesforce' did not find a matching property.
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1223 ms
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.5
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Salesforce]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:918)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Salesforce]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5058)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1175)
    ... 21 more

Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:918)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 19, 2014 2:41:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

I use tomcat7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod.

You need to add [Apache HTTP Client](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.5), [Apache HTTP Core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2) and [Commons Codec](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9) to your lib directory.